# Issues in accessing samba share on windows 10 only

Tags: samba

First diagnostics showed the following error:

> windows socket registry entries missing

Then I have removed the registry entries of winsock and winsock2 and reinstalled them by downloading and ran the following command:

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Now, the diagnostics shows different error:

> The device or resource (mysambashare.net) is not set up to
> accept connections on port "The File and printer sharing (SMB)".

The samba logs shows this:

> [2016/06/20 11:30:22.551172,  2]smbd/sesssetup.c:1413(setup_new_vc_session)
>
> setup_new_vc_session: New VC == 0, if NT4.x compatible we would close all old resources.
>
> [2016/06/20 11:30:22.577394,  1]auth/auth_server.c:422(check_smbserver_security)
>
> password server MYPASSWORDSERVER.NET rejected the password: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER
>
> [2016/06/20 11:30:22.593366,  2]auth/auth.c:314(check_ntlm_password)
>
> check_ntlm_password: Authentication for user [jbehara] -> [jbehara] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER .

The same above lines repeated 4 times continuously in samba logs.

No issues when I connect using the same credentials from another machine.

What could be the reason?

Comment: See duplicate at http://superuser.com/questions/1091310/issues-in-accessing-samba-share-on-windows-10-only

Comment: What version of Samba? What Linux-based distribution? Windows 10 or Windows 10 Professional? Can this Windows 10 client connect to any shares offered by a Windows server? Are your Windows client and Samba server domain joined? Please provide a copy of your `smb.conf` (redacted as appropriate).

Comment: If only one machine is affected, I wouldn't bother to try tracking it down. Reinstalling WIndows is the easiest solution; IMO there's just too many ways how a Windows can be damaged.

Comment: Hi..I am currently not with my system...But any possible explanation in the meanwhile why samba show such error?

Answer (score 0):

can you try to run : `netsh interface ip reset C:\resetlog.txt`
on your windows machine, and tell us if it does fix your problem, and if not fixed, provide version of samba and answer to roaima comment :

> What version of Samba? What Linux-based distribution? Windows 10 or
>   Windows 10 Professional? Can this Windows 10 client connect to any
>   shares offered by a Windows server? Are your Windows client and Samba
>   server domain joined? Please provide a copy of your smb.conf (redacted
>   as appropriate). – roaima